# Why doesn't Freeform Captcha show?

Tags: solspace-freeform, captcha

I am working on a contact page that uses Freeform 4.1.5 and for some reason the Captcha does not show.

I have taken the required step of confirming that captcha is required for logged in users, but the Captcha does not show whether I am logged in or not. Am I missing something?

Here is the form:

```
{exp:freeform:form form_name="contact" required="name|email" return="contact/thanks" require_captcha="yes" }
<!--basic info start here-->
<div class="top-form">
<div class="text-input">
<label for="name">name</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Your First & Last Name" />
</div>
<div class="text-input">
<label for="email">email</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="myname@example.com" />
</div>
<div class="text-input">
<label for="address">Address</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="address" placeholder="123 Coastal Lane" />
</div>
<div class="text-input">
<label for="address2">City, State, Zip</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Savannah, GA 31401" />
</div>
<div class="text-input">
<label for="phone">Phone Number</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="(912) 555-1234" />
</div>
</div>

{if freeform:captcha}
<div class="text-input">
{freeform:captcha}<br />
<label for="captcha">enter the word you see in the image</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="captcha" />
</div>
{/if} 

<!--questions & comments start here-->
<div class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
<!--questions & comments end here-->
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the permissions on your images/captchas directory. It needs to be writeable so the system can store Captcha images in there.

Comment: The previous developer had the wrong path in there. Thanks for the help.